# c# EPPlus (or OpenXML) setting Rowheight globally

Tags: c#, image, performance, openxml, epplus

I have a Table with many Images and want to adjust the rowheight
in this Post(with no answer yet) [Epplus row height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925549/epplus-row-height-issue) someone experienced the same performance issues.

To solve this is thought about setting the row height globally and disabling the custom Rowheight of each row. 
But e.g. `Row(4).CustomHeight = false;` will not use the DefaultHeigth ... it only adjusts the Heigth to fit the Text.

Question:
Is there a way to accomplish what I want(teach a row to take the height from defaultheight, after text was inserted) in EPPlus or even OpenXML whithout the performance problem?

I wrote a NUnit Test for reproducing (tested on windows 10 with excel installed). Im my real Aplication all Images are different, this is only for the test.

```
[Test]
public void SettingRowHeight() {
    ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet sheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100);
    int targetcolindex = 21;
    // adjust for scaling the problem 100 (10sec)is OK 
    // 500 will slow drastically(~19min)
    int rocount = 500;
    //Inserting Test Data
    for (int i = 1; i < rocount; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++)
        {
            sheet.Cells[i, k].Value = "test" + i;
        }
        var picture = sheet.Drawings.AddPicture("pic" + i.ToString() + targetcolindex.ToString(), bmp);
        picture.From.Column = targetcolindex - 1;
        picture.From.Row = i - 1;
        picture.From.ColumnOff = 2 * 9525; 
        picture.From.RowOff = 2 * 9525;                       
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Inserting {rocount} Cells: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 1; i < rocount; i++)
    {
        sheet.Row(i).Height = 50;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Set Height {rocount} Cells: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    sw.Stop();

    sw.Restart();
    sheet.Row(1).Height = 30;
    Console.WriteLine($"Set Height Row 1: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    sw.Restart();
    sheet.Row(2).Height = 30;
    Console.WriteLine($"Set Height Row 2: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    sw.Restart();
    sheet.Row(3).Height = 30;
    Console.WriteLine($"Set Height Row 3: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    sw.Restart();
    sheet.Row(rocount).Height = 30;
    Console.WriteLine($"Set Height Row {rocount}: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

    // trying to set the rowHeight globally so that above code can be skipped
    sheet.DefaultRowHeight = 50;
    // just for checking if something has changed
    sheet.Row(4).Height = 70;
    // this should remove the height and set it to Default value? if not: is there a way to do that?
    sheet.Row(4).CustomHeight = false;
    // this doesnt work either
    sheet.Row(6).Height = sheet.DefaultRowHeight;            
    sheet.Row(6).CustomHeight = false;
    // for looking over the result visually
    var filename = Path.GetTempFileName()+".xlsx";
    pkg.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(filename));
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
}
```

Edit: 
My current Workaround: setting the rowheigth before inserting any image.
Even removing all Images, setting Height, re-adding Images starts becoming faster starting at a certain image count in the document.

Comment: Since you already seem to go through each row to disable the `CustomHeight` property, couldn't you just go and set each row's height to a fixed height? Also, IMO, adding "many" images to Spreadsheets, usually to implement some sort of "catalog", is a mistake. Can it be done? Sure, to some extent, but you will soon hit a limit, since Spreadsheets are for data, not media. You could start by trying to use one of EPPlus methods that do bulk-inserting, like `LoadFromCollection`. Once your data is in the sheet set the size of each row to a fixed value and add the image.

Comment: Well I ended up doing excactly that, setting a fixed RowHeight upfront.

Comment: For the other Part: yes saving Images in Excel is bad
but the people here want it that way and the lists usually not exceed 2k lines. They pay me, so...
Does <code>LoadFromCollection</code> support Images? Would be interesting to know wheather the issues is tech related, EPPlus or OpenXML

Comment: I guessed so, but thought it would be helpful for others to point out that "Excel + images" isn't a great combination :) Anyway, I doubt that `LoadFromCollection` supports Images, as it requires `IEnumerable<string>` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank for your help :). I also found out that centering images with dynamic rowheights is really not possible. One can put the picture in the top left corner with `picture.EditAs = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.eEditAs.OneCell;` Well Excel and its Format is clearly not designed to handle Images in cells comfortably, else there would be a Button "Center Image in Cell" somewhere. (might be interesting aswell)

Comment: Your workaround is very helpful.